# Callback for arriving task in jobqueue?

Tags: c++, boost, threadpool

I was wondering if anyone has any good design suggestions for a jobqueue that notifies a processJob() function when tasks > 0. I'm using Boost and c++ and just trying to get a general idea of such a design. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would run `processJob()` in a separate thread, which uses a "condition variable" to gate whether it's running; and when adding something to the queue, notifying that c.v.

The loop logic is something like:

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mymutex);
while (!terminate)
{
    lock.lock();
    while (!Q.empty())
        jobCV.wait(lock);
    pItem = Q.pop();
    lock.unlock();
    pItem->process();
}
```

Remember that adding items to the queue also needs to lock on the same mutex. Also, you'll need a test before that `wait()` for the signal that will set `terminate`; and the setting of that signal also needs to call `notify()` on the c.v.

Comment: A good trick to solve the terminate problem is to queue a job that sets the terminate signal.  That means the terminate `bool` gets set in the job queue thread, and there isn't any need for memory barriers around it.  Second, you lock the lock, then wait on it: that seems questionable.  Is that supported?

Comment: Terminate-within-job is reasonable if the scoping works. The lock-before-wait is straight out of the boost c.v. documenation. As I understand it, within the `wait()`, the lock is unlocked so that other users can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If you already use boost library, it is convenient for you to just use boost::asio. an io_service object can be used to manage queue of jobs, since it guarantees the callbacks will be called in the order they are posted. and no hassle of locks if you only run io_service in one thread. Some sample code:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int job_number = 0;

struct Job
{
    virtual void run() { std::cout << "job " << ++job_number << " done" << '\n'; }
    virtual ~Job() {}
};

class Processor
{
private:
    boost::asio::io_service ioserv_;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work_;
    boost::thread thread_;

public:
    Processor() : ioserv_(), work_(ioserv_) {
    }

    void run() {   
        ioserv_.reset();
        thread_ = boost::thread (boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &ioserv_));
    }

    void stop() { 
        ioserv_.stop();
    }

    ~Processor() {
        stop();
        if (thread_.get_id() != boost::thread::id())
            thread_.join();
    }

    void processJob(boost::shared_ptr<Job> j)
    {
        j->run();
    }

    void addJob(boost::shared_ptr<Job> j)
    {
        ioserv_.post(boost::bind(&Processor::processJob, this, j));
    }

};

int main()
{
    Processor psr;
    psr.run();

    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        psr.addJob(boost::shared_ptr<Job>(new Job));

    sleep(1);

    return 0;
}
```